# PHP get different random array elements

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Actually I have this code to get differents elements depending of how many many values **$N** represents.

```
$my_array = array('a','b','c','d','e');
foreach( array_rand($my_array, $N) as $key )
{
  echo $my_array[$key];
}
```

For example if `$N = 2`, I will get two random elements and it works fine.

The problem is when `$N = 1`, I get the following error:

> WARNING Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

**Any idea or advice to fix it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick fix is:

```
$my_array = array('a','b','c','d','e');
// Cast result of `array_rand` to type "array"
foreach((array)array_rand($my_array, $N) as $key)
{
    echo $my_array[$key];
}
```

Comment: From php docs: When picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry. Otherwise, an array of keys for the random entries is returned. So u_mulder's fix fixes the problem because array_rand with $N=1 returns only one value and i'ts not array.

Answer (score 0):

If `array_rand`'s 2nd parameter is 1, it returns an element instead of an array containing the elements.

For example:

```php
$my_array = array('a','b','c','d','e');
array_rand($my_array, 1); // returns 'b'
array_rand($my_array, 2); // returns ['b', 'd']
```

You could do this:

```php
$randoms = array_rand($my_array, $N);
if ($N == 1) {
    $randoms = [$randoms];
}
foreach ($randoms as $key) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$my_array = array('a','b','c','d','e'); 
shuffle($my_array); 
if($my_array!=NULL)
{ 
    foreach($my_array as $data)
    { 
      echo $data;
    }
}
```